# Laravel twitter bootstrap: showing data on views

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am showing data to views where i have the following layout, And i have to use that layout.

I am querying my `DB` like this :

`$entertainments = App\TalentTag::all()->random(5);`

I have different `div` sizes that's why the problem occurs.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 small-boxes-left">
        @include("user/components/small-category-box")
        @include("user/components/small-category-box")
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 large-box-mid">
        @include("user/components/big-category-box")
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 small-boxes-right">
        @include("user/components/small-category-box")
        @include("user/components/small-category-box")
    </div>
</div>
```

Now how can `foreach()` the following layout to do this, I tried many ways but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$entertainments` variable that you get is a Collection, so you can use the method `chunk()` on it. It splits the Collection into smaller ones. Read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-chunk).

```
@foreach ($products->chunk(3) as $chunk)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($chunk as $product)
            <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $product->name }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The following method still shows all of the 5 records .
I don't know why ?