# Laravel chunk()

Tags: php, function, laravel, chunks

Laravel `chunk(1)` shows all five records.

I have the following code :

```
@foreach($entertainments->chunk(1) as $chunk)
    @foreach ($chunk as $entertainment)
        <p>{{ $entertainment->talent->title }}
          <span>{{ $entertainment->talent->realname }}
          </span>
        </p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I am querying like this `$entertainments = App\TalentTag::all()->random(5);`

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @arifmahmudrana , I have bootstrap `row` and that row have different size of columns , So i have to show only five records in that row but the simple foreach will not work because i have different size of columns in that single row .

Comment: @arifmahmudrana This is my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036443/laravel-twitter-bootstrap-showing-data-on-views/38036558#38036558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. If you want to display only first element, you should use `first()` method. If you want to achieve something else, you should explain what exactly you want, in addition `App\TalentTag::all()->random(5)` might not be the best solution if you have thousends of records.

Comment: I want random five records , I have specific bootstrap grid view, So i cannot use simple `foreach`, Because i have different size of columns in a single row. What should i use then ?

Comment: @Gammer Update your question then and explain in details, because at the moment I really don't know what you want to achieve and why cannot you just use foreach loop what seems to make sense in this case.

Comment: This is my question, Complete :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036443/laravel-twitter-bootstrap-showing-data-on-views/38036558#38036558

Comment: @Gammer So you got answer for that question. Why you ask a new one about same thing?

Comment: That is not working: Chunk(1) shows 5 records instead of one.

Comment: @Gammer It's not true, It shows single record, but because you use `foreach` loop you will finnally display each 1-element chunk (so in total 5)

Comment: So how can i avoid that ?

Comment: @Gammer What exatly you want to avoid? If you want to loop for all the elements all elements will be displayed - this is obvious, so it seems you are getting exactly what you want to achieve. As I said if not, you should update your question and show exact problem.

Comment: What i want to show the first record then second then third... And so on.

Comment: The html is here : pastebin.com/zJKh8rX3